# Multiple views in a Recyclerview gets changed instead of just one view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app with a Recyclerview having a Textview and a Button for each item. Initially, all the Textviews will be invisible. I want it to be visible when the corresponding button gets pressed. I managed to make this but it has a problem.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.so;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private WordListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mAdapter = new WordListAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

}
```

**WordListAdapter.java**:

```
package com.example.so;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public WordListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView itemTextview;
        private final Button itembutton;
        final WordListAdapter mAdapter;

        public WordViewHolder(View itemView, WordListAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            itembutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
            this.mAdapter = adapter;

            itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item, parent, false);
        return new WordViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

**wordlist_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button clicked!"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem with this is that when I press the first Button, the 15th Textview, in addition to the first Textview becomes visible. Similarly, when I press the 16th button, the 2nd Textview, in addition to the 
16th Textview becomes visible. The same goes for other buttons.

I'm not sure why two Textviews become visible when pressing a single button. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: where did you implement `onBindViewHolder()`??

Comment: I've overrided it in WordListAdpater.java. Nothing in it since this code is a simplified version of my original code

Comment: Try if...else... in onBindViewHolder()

Comment: I suppose your `selection` is not saved ? I suggest you to use some `data model` in which you save `checked (or button pressed state)` so it won't change upon recycled items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll and new RecyclerView items are being show to you, they are redrawn (recycled) and data is being newly inserted into them, using *onBindViewHolder()* function.

I would advise you to have some sort a *Collection* or an *Array* of visible items and use some logic in the *onBindViewHolder()* to hide or display them.

The *Constructor*

```
private boolean[] visibleItems;

public WordListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    visibleItems = new boolean[20];
}
```

and the *ViewHolder*

```
itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            visibleItems[pos] = true;
            notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }
    });
```

and the *onBindViewHolder()*

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(visibleItems[position]) 
        itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else itemTextview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

The same problem you have happens if there are EditTexts in the RecyclerView items and they are not set them using *setText()* inside the same function, but are only editable.

Comment: You're missing a notifyItemChanged call.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks! I also introduced a boolean array since the number of items in this specific case are always 20.

Answer (score 1):

When you are scrolling in a recycler view, the items are recycled. So create a variable to store the position of the item of which you clicked the button.

Implement in the `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, final int position){

        holder.itemTextview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if(currentPosition == position){

            holder.itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    // TODO: Implement this method

                    currentPosition = position;

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    }
```

The class `WordListAdapter` will look like this.

```
public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder>
{

    private Context context;
    private static int currentPosition=0;

    public WordListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private final TextView itemTextview;
        private final Button itembutton;

        public WordViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            itemTextview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            itembutton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        View mItemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item, parent, false);
        return new WordViewHolder(mItemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, final int position){

        holder.itemTextview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if(currentPosition == position){

            holder.itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    // TODO: Implement this method

                    currentPosition = position;

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement getItemId() method inside adapter.

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a visible/hidden status for each item. And change the status when the button clicked.

And in onBindViewHolder() you should use if/else to make the TextView visible/gone. Something like below. `data` is the array of your items. `VisibilityStatus` is the status i mentioned above. You can either put it in the data model, or keep it in another Array or `SparseBooleanArray`.

```
if (data.getVisibilityStatus(position)) {
    itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    itemTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this method in your adapter
**This method Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

**In adapter**

```
public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public WordListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView itemTextview;
        private Button itembutton;
//        final WordListAdapter mAdapter;

        public WordViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTextview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            itembutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item, parent, false);
        return new WordViewHolder(mItemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't promote copy-pasting. Explain what your code does.

Comment: @EugenPechanec , In my code I have implemented `getItemViewType()` method. This method **Return the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.** for more detail you can check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Answer (score 0):

Extension to [Viktor Stojanov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561261/6538876)  answer:

This behaviour is due to recyclerView's property of "**recycling**" the views.

When the list is scrolled, the views that become invisible are made eligible for reuse and those views are used again for the items that are about be be shown on the screen.
i.e. the same upper views are used, just the new data is binded using **onBindViewHolder()**.

I would suggest you to maintain an Arraylist of simple POJOs and refer their state to update the views in your recyclerView.
e.g.

```
public class Word{
     private boolean isVisible;
     private String content;

     //getters and setters for both properties
}
```

In bindViewHolder check the visibility of item and accordingly show the textView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Word currentWord = wordArraylist.get(position);
    if(currentWord.getVisibility()){
        itemTextView.setText(currentWord.getContent());
        itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else{
        if(itemTextView.getVisibility != View.INVISIBLE){
           itemTextview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your ViewHolder class you could set the onClickListener on the button to change the visibility, something like this:

```
    itembutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                Word currentWord = wordArraylist.get(getAdapterPosition());
                if(!currentWord.getVisibility()){
                     itemTextView.setText(currentWord.getContent());
                     itemTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
});
```